# create_autonomy deb

Tags: ros, deb, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Jacob Perron, Hello community,

is there a reason, why the excelent create_autonomy
(https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy)
package did not exists at the official ros (kinetic) repository ?

Thanks for a hint

Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264076/create_autonomy-deb/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Chrimo,

It's just one of those things that I never got to doing, but indeed plan to. I want to release *libcreate* first, followed by *create_autonomy*. I haven't felt any pressure to release, although I realize it will make it more accessible. If there is a strong desire from the community to have it released I will take the time to do so :)

Cheers,
Jacob

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0